# Text to speech in windows phone 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I want to use text to speech conversion in my WP7 application.

After searching on internet and different forums i found that there are some bing api available for doing this task..

this API allows only 5000 requests per month for free. [link for getting app Id](http://www.bing.com/developers/appids.aspx)

If i want to use an API for commercial use.. it can not be done with this API..

Is there any other API available for this or any free Google API..

Please give some directions and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for your problem is to target your app for **windows phone 8 OS**. trust me i tried many solutions to make my **windows phone 7 app** app use **TTS** . the quality that will get is not good . In windows phone 8 the TTS is very easy and the quality is amazing .

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

private async void AgainBtn_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    await synth.SpeakTextAsync("anything");

}
```

If you still want to target windows phone 7  use [Hawaii Research project](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/default.aspx)

Comment: i had already gone through this project but it is not available for commercial application use. any other option...?

Comment: for commercial application use [Dragon Mobile SDK](http://www.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=memberServices).